# Angular JS 1.5 - Refresh count

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to refresh a count periodically but do not want to go with $interval or with $timeout. Is there any other way to do this ?
I am using angular 1.5

Comment: do you need interval/count in minutes or seconds?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Please clarify what's the usecase of this. Additionally post any code which you've already tried. But, AFAIK, there is no way to do this without using those two services.

Comment: @VicJordan i need it in minutes

Comment: I guess that you want to refresh due a new data came from the server. The question is, is it your server? or are you using some api. If so, which API it is?

Comment: @31piy these APIs keep making server calls and its affecting performance of the screen. That's why i am looking for some other way to handle this. I tried looking around the web workers but it does not integrate well with angular, so can not use it.

Comment: @MoshFeu It's my server

Comment: So, you can use [`websocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) and save the interval. You can use a library such [ng-websocket](https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket)

Comment: @MoshFeu use of websocket will be heavy for our implementation

Comment: In one way or another you should fetch an updated data from the server. Either the server will tell you this (websocket) or the client should check in time to time (interval). The is no other LOGIC way yo do this. Web workers are also use interval, isn't?

Comment: Also, why web workers doesn't works well with angular? What is the exact problem? Have you reed this? https://shermandigital.com/blog/web-workers-with-angularjs/